# How to get a date difference as a negative number in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have this code in php to get the difference between two dates. I'm getting the difference but it's always positive. I need the difference to be negative when the final date has passed. I've tried format(), invert, but nothing seems to work.

```
function dias_transcurridos($fecha_i, $fecha_f)
{
$dias = (strtotime($fecha_i) - strtotime($fecha_f)) / 86400;
$dias = abs($dias);
$dias = floor($dias);
return $dias;
}
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
```

Then I call the code in my loop:

```
$elPlazo =  dias_transcurridos($row["DateEnd"], $hoy);
echo "<td>" . $elPlazo . " Días</td>\n";
```

How can I get $elPlazo (the difference) as a negative number when the end date has passed today?

Comment: Question needs to be updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have an `abs` in your code. `abs` will take the absolute value of any number (ie. remove the negative). Removing the `abs` will make your function return negative differences.

Answer (score 3):

I would also think about using the built-in PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and DateInterval objects because they can handle things like leap days:

```
<?php

function dias_transcurridos($fecha_i, $fecha_f)
{
    $i = new DateTime($fecha_i);
    $f = new DateTime($fecha_f);

    $interval = $i->diff($f);

    return $interval->days;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `DateTime` :

```php
$today = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime('2013-03-10');
 
$interval = $today->diff($date);
echo $interval->format("%r%a");
```

Comment: try that it worked for me